# Unable to boot from USB after sleep

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, sleep

I have Void Linux setup with full disk encryption. My boot partition with kernel and encryption key is located on USD drive. Everything is working fine until I turn my laptop into sleep mode, my ACPI handler script for sleep button is:

```bash
    button/sleep)
        case "$2" in
            SBTN|SLPB)
                # suspend-to-ram
                logger "Sleep Button pressed: $2, suspending..."
        sleep 0.5
                zzz
                ;;
            *)  logger "ACPI action undefined: $2" ;;
        esac
        ;;
```

The problem is that **sometimes** after sleep the laptop can't wake up and shows black screen. And after reboot, it can't find my USB drive with boot partition. To fix it, I need to insert another boot USB with grub, find first boot drive in grub and manually boot from first drive. Then I have reconfigure kernel to reinstall bootloadder with:

```
sudo xbps-reconfigure --force linux6.2-6.2.13_1
```

And after that it's working fine. Without kernel reconfiguration the problem will present on next boot, and the laptop won't find boot partition again.

My suspicion is that sleep mode can remove this drive from EFI boot manager, because when I checked `efibootmgr` output, I didn't find my USB drive here.

I see this problem not very often, about every 10 sleep. The duration of sleep doesn't matter: the laptop can be suspended in sleep mode for one day and wake up fine, but it can break after 10 minutes of sleep.

How I can fix this problem with sleep?